# Zend - plugin not found in the registry

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, plugins, validation

I've been researching about this for hours, but in vain... I have a Zend application and these are two classes from it:

```
class Application_Form_Disciplines extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {
      $this->addElementPrefixPath('My_Validate', '../library/validate', 'validate');
      ...
      $credits->addValidator('My_Validate_NumericBetween');
      ...
    }
}

class My_Validate_NumericBetween extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when i submit the form i get "Plugin by name 'My_Validate_NumericBetween' was not found in the registry; used paths: My_Validate_: ../library/validate/ Zend_Validate_: Zend/Validate/". The class named "My_Validate_NumericBetween" is found in project/library/validate. I've tried a lot of things found on the net, but nothing worked.

Thank you!

Comment: what's the php filename for My_Validate_NumericBetween class ?

Comment: it's the same as the class, My_Validate_NumericBetween

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->addElementPrefixPath('My_Validate', APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/validate', 'validate');
$credits->addValidator('NumericBetween');
```

*Side note*: Typical PSR-0 classname/file scheme would be to have the class `My_Validate_NumericBetween` stored in the file `library/My/Validate/NumericBetween.php`, rather than `library/validate/NumericBetween.php` (which I infer you are using).

Comment: it's not working...i still get "plugin not found"...do i have to write something inside Bootstrap class or in application.ini?

Comment: I see from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9841149/131824) that your file name is `My_Validate_NumericBetween,php`; that's not gonna work. Change to `library/My/Validate/NumericBetween.php`.

Comment: can you help me with another problem, please? this is it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921552/zend-new-controller-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `Bootstrap.php`, it will save you some typing in the future too

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('My_');
```

Comment: the problem is still there :|

Answer (score 0):

rename the file to NumericBetween.php

the class name should remain My_Validate_NumericBetween